# Using R, how to split a data frame's column and then break into multiple rows?

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I have a data frame with one field that is a string containing a comma-separated list of names.  I want to expand the data frame so that I have multiple rows from each original row, the number of rows being the number of names in the list.  So, I want to change something like

```
df <- data.frame(f1=c("a","b"), f2=c("b","e"), f3=c("a,b,c", "a,d"))
df
f1  f2  f3
a   b   a,b,c
d   e   a,d
```

into

```
df
f1  f2  f3
a   b   a
a   b   b
a   b   c
d   e   a
d   e   d
```

I suspect that dplyr and/or reshape2 are the tools for the job, but I'm not sure how to apply them in this case.

Comment: Specifically look at the `cSplit` function in that answer. Just use `sep=","` for your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `apply`:

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  do.call(expand.grid, strsplit(x, ","))
})))
#   f1 f2 f3
# 1  a  b  a
# 2  a  b  b
# 3  a  b  c
# 4  b  e  a
# 5  b  e  d
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add your answer to the duplicate question so we can continue to point others there for the same question.

Comment: @MrFlick OK, I added my answer to the other question too.

Comment: Hey this is a really great solution, and much faster than the splitstackshape package functions,which also gave NAs, if the f3 column above is of different lengths. Now is there a way to create a progress bar for this, as I have a really large working dataset. Thanks a lot